# Can I write a server hook that warns on files containing Git conflict markers?

Tags: eclipse, git, gitolite

I've administering a Git repo through Gitolite which has about 40 devs and 35,0000 files. We've only just switched from CVS so a lot of people are struggling to adjust to the differences.

Once such problem is our users use Eclipse and EGit for their work. In CVS, all merging is via Team Sync and conflicts are resolved via a 3-way diff tool. In EGit, a merge conflict is decorated with markers it's possible for devs to forget these markers or assume they get removed somehow. Not all these issues would show up as compile errors either since the conflict could be in a batch file, or a config file.

More experience with the tools might solve most of these problems but I would like to add a hook to Gitolite which checks any pushed .java, .bat, .xml or .properties file for any line that starts with exactly `<<<<<<<`, `=======`  or `>>>>>>>` followed by any other character and adds a warning message to the user highlighting the problem and the file it is in.

That way I hope they will catch the error, correct it straight away and learn from their mistake. The alternative is potentially hours wasted wondering why some code is failing to run properly.

I assume the regexes would be easy enough, e.g. `^>>>>>>>[^>]`. So it's more a matter of if Gitolite allows this and the effort required to test and produce such a script? Does anyone have an example script I could adapt which does this?

I would only be warning users for the time being, but I would like to flip a switch and outright reject commits later.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to define a [VREF (which is like a plain update hook)](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/vref.html).

You can then apply this VREF rule like any other R/W gitolite rule within a repo (maning you can apply this rule only for certain people/branch/folders/files)

You can easily parse the content of a file being pushed, like in [this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2540857/6309):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read old_sha1 new_sha1 refname; do
    echo "ns: " $new_sha1;
    echo "os: " $old_sha1;

    echo "----"

    git ls-tree -r $new_sha1 | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | cut -f 1 | while read file; do
        git cat-file blob $file
        # do your grep here
    done; 


done
```

Comment: This should be included by default.